# In perl mason what is the difference between .m file and .mi file?

Tags: perl, mason

I would want to understand the difference between a .m file and .mi file in Perl/Mason.

As per the mason components docs:

> .mi - internal component. An internal component can only be accessed from other components.

I can see that i can call specific methods in written in a .mi file by

`$m->comp('test.mi:randomMethod', arg1=> 'blah')`

Can i do the same for my .m file as well ? As all the existing places i searched online . i only found a file with no methods and the entire file is executed when called.

`$m->comp('test.m', arg1=> 'blah')` runs the entire file as it has no methods.

So,

1. I want to know the difference between both file extensions
2. Can i have methods similar to .mi file in .m file and call those methods specifically?
3. When should i choose .m file and when .mi file ?

Comment: Have you tried? Or are you evaluating whether to use Mason at all before trying?

Comment: There is an exiting .m file which is doing something. It doesnt have any methods. But where as .mi file has methods and specifically those methods alone can be called. is that possible in .m file ? I want to understand before trying them out.

Comment: I have never used Mason, so I have no idea. I was trying to help you clarify your question. But my suggestion is you just create a new .m file, put a _hello world_ method in it and try. :)

Comment: ok thanks for your help.

Comment: *"the mason components docs"* Do you mean the documentation for [Mason::Manual::Components](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason::Manual::Components)?

Answer (score 4):

I am kind of new to Mason, but ran into the similar questions before, I'll try my best to answer the questions, but I can be very wrong...

> 1. I would want to know the difference between the both file extensions

According to my very limited experience with mason, the .m files are somewhat equivalent to the .mc file, which is a top-level component that serves to a request.

And the .mi files are internal components that carries business logic for helping preparing data/content for the top-level .m file.

> 2. Can i have methods similar to .mi file in .m file and call those methods specifically ?

Yes, you can define a method in .m file, can call it just like .mi file, for example:

$m->comp('/foo/bar.m:start')

I've seen working codes doing that.

> 3. When should i chose .m file and when .mi file ?

I guess this goes to the differences between .m and .mi files.

For public logic, like pulling an image, you can put the logic in the .m file.

For business logic or dealing with sensitive information, do it in .mi file.

Comment: @Jolta this looks like a perfectly valid answer. Why flag it as "A different question posted as an answer"?

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever seen **.mp**, **.mc**, and **.mi** for *Mason Perl*, *Mason Component*, and *Mason Internal* respectively. But they are configurable

If you read *PARAMETERS TO THE new() CONSTRUCTOR* from the [`Mason::Interp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason::Interp#PARAMETERS-TO-THE-new()-CONSTRUCTOR) documentation, you wqill see that you can specify a value for `pure_perl_extensions` to change the default from **.mp**, and `top_level_extensions` for **.mc**

There's every reason to keep to these standards, unles you are working with two conflicting standards and need one to move out of the way

I don't know whether **.mi** is required, but it seems unlikely. And I don't remember ever seeing a simple **.m**. Where have you seen this yourself, and shouldn't it be a **.mi** file?—i.e. is the example that you have seen an internal component?